# Multiple Aggregate Function in SELECT with different conditions in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Given these two tables:

```
Goals(Id,Player,isAuto)
Players(Id,Name,Team)
```

I want to know the total amount of goals and auto-goals for each team.

My query so far:

```
SELECT p.Team,COUNT(g.Id) AS Total,COUNT(g.isAuto) AS Auto
FROM Players p
JOIN Goals g
  ON p.Id=g.Player
WHERE g.isAuto=True
GROUP BY p.Team
```

The problem with this query is that the condition of `isAuto` affects the result of the first `COUNT` function and I can't figure out how to make it so the condtion on `isAuto` only affects the corresponding `COUNT`.

Comment: You can use COUNT or SUM of a CASE END expression so that the rows are not impacted by that logic.  `SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN x > 5 AND g.isAuto=True THEN 1 END), ...`.  Notice that COUNT and SUM will ignore the null produced when the `ELSE `clause is not present, or you use `ELSE null END` explicitly in the expression.

Comment: @Jon Armstrong Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.Team
     , COUNT(g.Id) AS Total
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN g.isAuto = True THEN 1 END) AS Auto
  FROM Players p
  JOIN Goals g
    ON p.Id=g.Player
 GROUP BY p.Team
;
```

Note: For cases where we wish to show players / teams which have no goals, use an outer join.  Otherwise, inner join is fine.

Comment: I don't fully understand the note on using the outer join for players with no goals: if a player has no goals it shouldn't appear in the Goals table so it wouldn't be included in the counts anyway right?

Comment: That's fine.  My comment was just in case you wanted a report for all teams/users, even if they scored no goals.  If you don't need that detail, the inner join is fine.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem with this query is that the condition of isAuto affects the result of the first COUNT function and I can't figure out how to make it so the condtion on isAuto only affects the corresponding COUNT.

The results of aggregate functions are computed on the rows from the source specified by the `FROM` clause that satisfy any criteria specified via a `WHERE` clause.  You can think of it as the rows being filtered by the `WHERE` criterion before they are aggregated into the groups over which the aggregate functions are computed.  You cannot make a `WHERE` clause apply to only a proper subset of the aggregate functions that are selected.

But there are other approaches to computing the result you are trying to get.  In particular, if `goals.isauto` is an integer field constrained to contain only values `0` and `1` then you can determine `SUM(g.isauto)` instead of `COUNT(g.isauto)`:

```
SELECT p.Team,COUNT(g.id) AS Total, SUM(g.isAuto) AS Auto
FROM Players p
JOIN Goals g
  ON p.Id=g.Player
WHERE g.isAuto=True
GROUP BY p.Team
```

If the domain of `isauto` is something else then you can compute the sum of a `CASE` or other expression that performs an appropriate conversion.  For example, `SUM(CASE WHEN g.isAuto > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

Note also that `COUNT(g.id)` counts the number of rows in the group that have non-null `g.id`, but if `g.id` is a non-nullable primary key then that will always be all rows, more clearly expressed as `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, in this case isAuto is a boolean so I used the the sum case.